# Visual c++ load rtf document contains images and text in richedit box?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, richedit, visual-c++-2005, richedit-control

I am currently working on a project. I have an rtf file which contains some text and images both. I need to display those images and text from rtf to richtextbox in Visual C++. We are not using .Net frameworks or MFC's so everything is in Visual C++ only.

I do'nt have any idea how to do it. If anyone can guide me then it will be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here's the link to WinAPI's [Rich Edit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787605%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: @Proxy actually I already looked into it. But did not find anything. Please suggest me if you have anything else. Thanks anyway for your time. :)

Answer (score 0):

RichTextBox cannot load HTML. It can load only RTF or plain text.

There are 3rd party components that can convert HTML to RTF, but they don't really do a good job especially when dealing with images. I had done intensive research on this for my sticky notes product Notezilla.

You can use the Web Browser control to show your HTML.

Comment: If rtf contains an image then it can display that image.

Comment: Yes. RichTextBox can display images. See the example here: http://www.conceptworld.com/Notezilla/Insert-Pictures-Inside-Sticky-Notes

Comment: Where is example on this link did not find it.

Comment: One more thing is I am asking suppose any rtf contains text + images both then can we display it in richtext.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9541/A-Rich-Edit-Control-That-Displays-Bitmaps-and-Othe - although this is MFC example you should be able to get an idea about how to use it. Yes, both text & images are posible in rich text box.

Comment: Thanks yaar it didn't work but still helpful. Something is better than nothing.